# Arduino Uno R3 to Wemos D1 R2 project migration - Pinout problems

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, pins, port-mapping

So i've chosen to purchase a Wemos D1 R2 board in order that my old Arduino Uno R3 projects can get some new IoT features. However, even if my code is working in Uno perfectly, i want to test it using D1 before adding features. My problem is that, even if i have found tables showing differences between the 2 boards' pinouts, i cannot understand the correspondence between the pinouts.

So i am giving you the table below. Let's say i want to define echo and trigger pins for a sensor in my code. For example:

```
#define TRIGGER_PIN 4
#define ECHO_PIN 3
```

That would be pins D3 and D4 at my Uno. But i cannot understand which those pins would be in Wemos D1 R2. Also, my two boards can be seen below for comparison

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky thing with the WeMos boards is the pin notation is different from other Arduino boards.

Sometimes you will see the digital pins on Arduino boards referenced with the D*n* notation. For example: "Connect the HC-SR04's Trig pin to D4 on the Uno". In fact some boards such as the Nano even use the D*n* pin notation on their silkscreen. This is just a way of further differentiating the pins from the A*n* pins. You will only refer to that pin by the number 4 in your code.

The WeMos boards are different. You actually need to use `D3` and `D4` in your code to control the pins marked D3 and D4 on the silkscreen:

```cpp
#define TRIGGER_PIN D4
#define ECHO_PIN D3
```

We can take a peek at the source code of the [ESP8266 core for Arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/) to see why:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.4.0/variants/d1_mini/pins_arduino.h#L40-L50

```cpp
static const uint8_t D0   = 16;
static const uint8_t D1   = 5;
static const uint8_t D2   = 4;
static const uint8_t D3   = 0;
static const uint8_t D4   = 2;
static const uint8_t D5   = 14;
static const uint8_t D6   = 12;
static const uint8_t D7   = 13;
static const uint8_t D8   = 15;
static const uint8_t RX   = 3;
static const uint8_t TX = 1;
```

Now you can see that if you use your original code:

```cpp
#define TRIGGER_PIN 4
#define ECHO_PIN 3
```

That would actually be referring to the pins marked D2 and RX on the WeMos D1 R2!

Comment: Perfect answer to sort that out. To the point and clear! Thanks.

Comment: If i choose to use numbers with Ds, f.e. TRIGGER_PIN D4, will i connect jumper wire of trigger to D2(Arduino pin) or to D4 (physical D4 on Wemos)?

Comment: Use the D*n* names, as marked on the WeMos board, in your code and the pin with that marking will be used. i.e. if you write `D4` in your code then connect the wire to the pin marked D4 on the board.